ASP.NET MVC view result export see html
I am trying to see the html in the ViewResult I was thinking there was a method view ToHtml but I am getting an error contain a definition for ToHtml. Is there a way to see the html in this method?
view.ToHtml()


Error CS1061: 'ViewResult' does not contain a definition for 'ToHtml' and no accessible extension method 'ToHtml' accepting a first argument of type 'ViewResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:
public ViewResult Export(string versionKey, bool? hideFooter, bool? hideHeader)
{
    var template = TemplatesDataService.GetTemplate(versionKey);

    AuthorizeReviewer(template.VersionKey, template.VersionNumber);

    var model = GetTemplateModel(template);

    var notesProvider = new TemplateNotesProvider();
    var notes = notesProvider.GetNotes(model).ToList();

    model.Notes = notes.Where(n => n.IsApplicable);
    model.NotesCollection = notesProvider.GetNotesCollection(model);

    var footer = SettingsDataService.GetCurrentSettings().PdfFooterTemplate;
    footer = footer.Replace("[[last-edited-year]]", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())
                   .Replace("[[last-edited-date]]", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

    ViewBag.Footer = footer;
    ViewBag.HideFooter = hideFooter.HasValue && hideFooter.Value;
    ViewBag.HideHeader = hideHeader.HasValue && hideHeader.Value;

    var view = this.View("Export/Index", model);

    return View("Export/Index", model);
}


possible duplicate of How to render an ASP.NET MVC view as a string?

Try something like this
if you're looking to render the HTML content of a ViewResult, you can use the ViewEngineResult and HtmlHelper to render the view manually
public static string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, object model){
var viewEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, null);
if (viewEngine.View == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"View '{viewName}' not found.");
}

using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    var ctx = new ViewContext(
        controllerContext,
        viewEngine.View,
        new ViewDataDictionary(model),
        new TempDataDictionary(),
        sw
    );
    
    viewEngine.View.Render(ctx, sw);
    return sw.ToString();
}
}

